# Sinon - How to make a function thats called indirectly return something

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, sinon

I have been struggling on how i can mock a function so that i can return a fake value from that function.

I have a simple script that can make a api call, however this api call has two parameters. One parameter is provided through the parameter of the parent function, the other one is provided by making a call to another function. The return value from this function is what i need to mock.

The full code is quite complex, that's why i made a small sample of what i mean. Firstable i have the function `makeTheCall`. Within that function i call a function called `setParameters`.

```
const setParams = require('setParams.js');

module.exports.makeTheCall = (event) => {
  const params = setParams('GET', '/todos/1');
  const postData = {
    name: event.name,
    location: event.location
  }

  console.log(params); //dynamic params 'method' and 'callpath' are both undefined here (should be 'GET' and '/todos/1')

  return doARequest(params, postData).then((result) => {
    return result;
  }).catch((error) => {
    return error;
  })
}
```

The `setParams` function is not so difficult. It just returns an object that contains some static and some dynamic values.

```
module.exports.setParams = (method, callPath) => {
  return {
    host: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
    port: 433,
    method: method,
    path: callPath
  }
}
```

Now, here is where the interesting part comes into play. When write a simple test the call cannot go through. This is, of course, because it cannot resolve the dynamic values `method` and `callPath`.

```
const makeTheCall = require('makeTheCall.js');

it('runs a happy flow scenario', () => {
  const event = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    location: 'Somewhere'
  }

  return makeTheCall(event)
    .then(response => {
      //Do some usefull testing here
    });
});
```

My question is how i can mock the return value of the setParams method so that it will return something like:

```
{
  host: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
  port: 433,
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/todos/1'
}
```

This way i can invoke my API call in my test without it causing an error. I have been looking into mocking using sinon, particularly into sinon stubs, like:

```
const params = setParams('GET', '/todos/1');
sinon.stub(params).returns({
  host: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
  port: 433,
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/todos/1'
});
```

However i think i overlook something because this does not work. The documentation is nice but after a couple of hours struggling and trying things i start to feel kinda lost.

Who knows / can point me in the right direction on how to mock the return value of the setParams function? An example will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need not mock `setParams`. What is that you want to test? From the example you described you need to mock `doARequest` method which would return a promise based on your mock-conditions, and check if `doARequest` is called with `params` and `postData` and check if it returns mocked-response or error based on your mocked conditions(whether a promise is rejected or resolved in the stub method of `doARequest`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling `sinon.stub` quite right. `stub()` needs an object and a function that is a property of that object. If you import with:

```
 const setParams = require('setParams.js');
```

Then `setParams` will be the `modules.export` object and `setParams` will be a property, so you can stub it with something like:

```
let fakeParam = {
    host: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
    port: 433,
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/todos/1'
}

let paramStub = sinon.stub(params, 'setParams').returns(fakeParam)
```

In the broader picture it's not really clear what you are trying to test. With unit tests you generally try to reduce everything down to one small thing you want to assert. So in this case maybe you want to assert that when you call `makeTheCall` `doARequest` is called with the params returned from `setParams`. In that case you might also stub `doARequest`. Then you can assert with `sinon.calledWith(doARequestStubb, fakeParam)`. You can have `doARequestStubb` resolve with a promise to the code doesn't break.

Comment: I got the general idea. I got it working but i can't figure out how i can use the fake return value in the then/catch clause of a promise. I have opened a separate topic for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54046151/mock-and-assert-a-function-call-in-a-promise). Can you maybe help me understand this part better?